# Pipelines - Average build time

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I wonder if there is a way to get the average build time from bitbucket pipelines. (API ?)

We have several projects in parallel and build times can go from 20s to 4-5 minutes depending on what each project needs.

Since this build process has slack reporting, i would like to introduce the reporting with a "The average build time for this project is 3.2 minutes" so the people know when to expect the end or to worry about a failure.

Anyone has any lead about meta information about the bitbucket pipelines that could be accessed from within the pipeline ?

Comment: This would probably be better as a feature request for the Pipelines team; I don't know that they monitor StackOverflow for these sorts of feedback.

Comment: Thanks dimo, can you point out where to do so if you know ?

Comment: Check the [Pipelines FAQ](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-pipelines-faq-827104769.html) - there's a "How can I give you feedback?" question.